# What happens if I reinstall Dropbox and copy a partial Dropbox folder?

Tags: dropbox

I'm planning to install Dropbox on a new machine. To speed up the sync process, I'd like to move over the files I already have on my current machine.

However, I currently have Smart Sync enabled, and some files/directories are "Online Only".

What happens if I install Dropbox on the new machine, copy the files I have locally on my machine to the target Dropbox folder, and start the Dropbox client?

- will Dropbox sync the missing files to my new machine?
- or will Dropbox remove the missing files from my Dropbox account?

In other terms, what's the sync algorithm in this case?

*Note: the new machine is running Linux, so Smart Sync is not (yet) available there.*

Answer (score 0):

If you copy your Dropbox folder to a new PC and then start the Dropbox client, all missing files will be downloaded, not deleted. Only if you delete files/folders *while* the client is running they get deleted in the Dropbox cloud as well. With Smart Sync, it behaves the same if it's activated on *both* machines.

In your case however, it's different as the new machine doesn't have Smart Sync. In the Dropbox Smart Sync help [here](https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/sync-uploads/smart-sync) it says that *"If you move online-only content outside of the local Dropbox folder, the content downloads to that location"*. This means if you copy your Dropbox folder to the new location while having internet access on the old machine, then all "Online Only" files will be downloaded first and then copied. Afterwards on the new machine Dropbox behaves like it normally would without Smart Sync.

But as always, an additional backup is advisable ;)